# Are Ivy and Gradle configurations equal?

Tags: configuration, gradle, ivy

In Gradle we have a configuration which consists of dependencies and one configuration can extends multiple others, but how is in Ivy and do we have full equivalency between Ivy and Gradle's configurations?

**Ivy**

```
<conf name="runtime" visibility="public" description="ala-bala" extends="compile"/>
```

**Gradle:**
??

```
configurations {
    compile {
        description = 'ala-bala'
    }
    runtime {
        extendsFrom compile
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gradle's configurations are heavily inspired from Ivy (not Ant), but they aren't fully equivalent to Ivy's configurations (and we'd have to discuss what you mean by "equivalent"). They will be mapped to Ivy configurations when Gradle generates an `ivy.xml`.